# Flutter iOS app not running after updating Firebase to latest versions - Terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, pubspec

After updating Firebase versions, iOS Flutter app does not run (even after building successfully).

The error I'm getting is:

```
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Object for handle already exists: 1'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

As of today, these are the latest versions I've updated.

```bash
  firebase_core: 2.4.0
  firebase_crashlytics: 3.0.8
  firebase_analytics: 10.0.8
  firebase_performance: 0.9.0+8
  firebase_remote_config: 3.0.8
```

P.S: Android version builds and runs with no problem after this update.